# How to return JSON from Linq to Entities query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a difficult time understanding my options to return json from a query in my control, as there seems to be many ways to do this. Any clarification would be very much appreciated.

I would like to return json from the following:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
private MyEntities context = new MyEntities();

public IQueryable <string> Get()
{

    var query =
        from MY_ENTITY_1 in my_entity_1
        from MY_ENTITY_2 in my_entity_2
        from MY_ENTITY_3 in my_entity_3

        where
             MY_ENITITY_1.something == MY_ENTITY_2.something

        select new
            {
                Result1 = MY_ENTITY_1.FOO1,
                Result2 = MY_ENTITY_2.FOO2,
                Result3 = MY_ENTITY_3.FOO3
            };

    foreach (var myResults in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myResults);
    };

    return myResults; // JSON?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the `ApiController` automatically converts returned objects to JSON when those actions are invoked:

```
public IQueryable <MyGetResult> Get()

{

    var query =
        from MY_ENTITY_1 in my_entity_1
        from MY_ENTITY_2 in my_entity_2
        from MY_ENTITY_3 in my_entity_3

        where
             MY_ENITITY_1.something == MY_ENTITY_2.something

        select new MyGetResult
            {
                Result1 = MY_ENTITY_1.FOO1,
                Result2 = MY_ENTITY_2.FOO2,
                Result3 = MY_ENTITY_3.FOO3
            };
    return query;
}

public class MyGetResult
{
    public Foo Result1 {get;set;}
    public Foo Result2 {get;set;}
    public Foo Result3 {get;set;}
}
```

WebAPI uses a strategy called ["Content Negotiation"](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) to determine what data type the caller wants, and automatically serializes the results accordingly.

Comment: Thank you StriplingWarrior, that looks much improved and clear. If multiple rows are returned, s it necessary to iterate over them here before returning 'return query'? Should that happen client side? Or is it just handled?

Comment: @ChristopherCrisis: The framework should just be able to handle it: it will probably return JSON that represents an object with an array on it. I would personally call `return query.ToList();`, and create the context in a `using` statement to ensure that it gets disposed. Though you may want to read up a little more, as I seem to remember WebApi being able to add OData support to actions that return IQueryables.

Answer (score 1):

From `ApiController` it appears that you are using `WebAPI`. **You don't have to return JSON or XML from your method**, instead simply return the object. It is the responsibility of the caller to specify the return data type.

For example, if you browse to your service through IE you will get JSON back, since IE uses JSON as the default return type. If you browse the same URL in Chrome, you will get back `XML`, since thats the default for Chrome, it depends on the `ContentType` of the request if it is `ContentType: application/json` then you will get JSON back.